# Tax deduction for US-based employer paying in Bitcoin to overseas contractor

Tags: legal, taxes, accounting

My employer can write off business expenses (my salary) if he pays me via wire transfer, PayPal, Payoneer and some other international payment systems. Is there a tax-deductible method for him to buy Bitcoin and send it to my wallet (or to my account from where I can withdraw to my wallet)?

I'm no good in legal terms, so feel free to edit the question if you understand what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't at all see why he couldn't purchase bitcoin through Coinbase or similar and deduct it. That should be entirely deductible, even the fees paid to buy the bitcoin (bank fees plus whatever Coinbase is charging these days).

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's better if he sends it to my account (with my real name) rather than to my (anonymous) bitcoin wallet. Anyway it needs accountant consultation.

Comment: Yes. I would think it would be treated just like a bank transfer, except that he's purchasing the foreign currency himself and transferring it. Don't forget to accept!