# Are Bitcoin/cryptocurrency trades or earnings taxed in Albania?

Tags: taxes, europe

Are Bitcoin/cryptocurrency trades or earnings taxed in Albania as of the beginning of 2020?
I've also seen some news of a European standard that countries are adopting. This may hold the answer to the question. I also understand Albanian law changed in the middle of 2020.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have lawyers, even if there are few, its offtopic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not the appropriate place to ask for tax advice.

Comment: This isn't for free legal or tax advice. It's for student research.

Comment: Similar questions related to taxes have been accepted and [answered](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/tax-deduction-for-us-based-employer-paying-in-bitcoin-to-overseas-contractor) . Policy should be conistent